# How to store multiple integer key with value in single column with laravel migration

Tags: laravel, migration

[image]

In feedbacks table there would be a integer column 
A user can input 1,4,5 as feedback.
How to design this column in laravel migration ?

I am thinking of json column, which is not serving my purpose of integer column.

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't have multiple IDs in a single column, as this breaks most database normalization. Take a look at many-to-many relationships in Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many, which has 2 tables and a pivot table between them. Multiple rows are inserted into the pivot table, one for each ID (1, 4, 5) passed, and you use that to map the other tables to each other.

Comment: $table->tinyInteget('target_grade')->comment(
                '0: 1年生以上',
                '1: 2年生以上',
                '2: 3年生以上',
                '3: 4年生以上',
                '4: 5年生以上',
                '5: 6年生以上',
            )->nullable(false);  


What about this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use json column in your migration or has to move to pivot table.

```
$table->json('json_column_name');
```

After that If you need to use its relations you can use [this](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations) package.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a many-to-many relation, you just could make the column as integer and use the model to control how the columns is stored

```
class Feedback extends Model{
   /**
   * list of types
   */
   const TYPES = [
       self::LEADERSHIP => 'Leadership',
       self::BOLDNESS => 'Boldness',
       self::EXTERNAL_MIND => 'External mind',
       ...
   ];

   // Define constants
   const LEADERSHIP = 1;
   const BOLDNESS = 2;
   const EXTERNAL_MIND = 3;
   ...
}
```

The migration

```
use App\Models\Feedback;
...
Schema::create('feedbacks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    ...
    $table->tinyInteger('type')->default(Feedback::LEADERSHIP);
});
```

For validation

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use App\Models\Feedback;
...
Validator::make($data, [
    'type' => [
        'required',
        Rule::in(Feedback::TYPES),
    ],
]);
```